Spin 1/2 or spin 1, spin 2 systems?
I have a simple question of how to know what spin system my system has? For example, I am working with manganese monolayers on a metallic substrate. How do I know what is the spin state of Mn? I can calculate that easily for ions, but how do I do that for thin films of magnetic metals?

If you don't get a suitable answer here, consider to ask on Matter Modeling SE.
